# Run bash script using full path

Tags: linux, bash

Can someone explain me why my script can't be run from other directory than this one where it is created?
My script *start.sh* in directory */root/etlegacy/* :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S etserver /root/etlegacy/etlded
```

Everything works fine when I am in /root/etlegacy/and run script through:

```
./start.sh
```

But It is not working when I am elsewhere in the file system, even If I am using full path to script i.e

```
/root/etlegacy/start.sh
```

Comment: What does "not working" look like?  What is the failure pattern?  What does the system say when you attempt to run with the absolute path?

Comment: If the script is written with assumptions about its current working directory, that's arguably a bug/limitation in the script itself, not an issue with how you're calling it. But if you wanted to work around that -- `cd /root/etlegacy && exec /usr/bin/screen -d -m -S etserver /root/etlegacy/etlded`, or whatnot.

Comment: (That said, if your goal here is to invoke a long-running service, consider using a proper process supervision system such as systemd instead; that will take care of starting the process on boot, restarting it if it fails [if you want that], ensuring that logs are archived on disk, etc.)

Comment: In fact I don't receive any statement from system (The same as I would run It by ./start.sh). It looks like script was executed properly but when I look for "screen" to detach there is no one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your script as you wrote it. The problem is more likely being in `/root/etlegacy/etlded` which may require to be run into the `/root/etlegacy` directory. Try to change the code into this:

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd /root/etlegacy
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S etserver /root/etlegacy/etlded
popd
```

Comment: A few notes: First, if the `cd` fails (or in your case the `pushd`), it's generally a good idea to abort, not to run the rest of your code in the wrong directory. Thus, `cd ... || exit` or `cd ... && thing-that-should-be-run-in-other-directory` is best-practice. See also [BashPitfalls #19](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cd_.2Ffoo.3B_bar).

Comment: Second: I'd strongly advise avoiding `pushd` here. Running `popd` at the end serves no purpose (your script's working directory disappears with the rest of its state when it exits), but prevents the shell from being able to `exec` the copy of screen (thus letting its PID be replaced, signals be directly delivered, etc). Moreover, the use of `pushd` and `popd` is presently the only thing that makes this script outside of baseline POSIX sh (and thus able to run with any compliant `#!/bin/sh`).

Comment: This solution make script working. So I can omit the `popd` at the end of script?

Comment: it depends on how you invoke it. If you do `bash /path/of/script` or just `/path/of/script` you can even replace the `pushd` with an ordinary `cd` and remove the `popd`, but if you invoke it in the same shell, such as `source /path/of/script` or `. /path/of/script` leaving it with `pushd`/`popd` will prevent the current directory of the calling shell to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works fine when I am in `/root/etlegacy/etlded` [...] and run script through: `./start.sh`

...

> But It is not working when [...] I am using full path to script i.e `/root/etlegacy/start.sh`

Well, there's your problem. It sounds like the full path of your script is actually:

```
/root/etlegacy/etlded/start.sh
```

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake now update **etlded** is name of executable program. The directory is /root/etlegacy

Comment: @jadupl Can you update your question? Please copy-paste actual output straight from a terminal, don't try to type out your problem by hand. Also copy-paste all errors along with it.

Comment: That was the only one mistake in question. As I mentioned in comments above I don't receive any statement from system (script is simple just should open screen with executed program **etlded**) There is no return statement after running successfully either. When I run it by ./start.sh new screen is created and I can attach to it, but when runned by full path there is no screen created.

Comment: @jadupl Please update the question anyways. That way, when someone finds this question a year from now, they immediately see if this is their problem and can skip to the answer. Currently they have to read all the comments first